# How to correctly install NZXT Kraken x63

Tags: cooling

I've bought a NZXT Kraken x63 and I have a Corsair Carbide Series 275Q chassis and Gigabyte Aorus Master X570 motherboard (links to specs are at the bottom).

I have two questions regarding the installation:

1. What is the correct (or best) physical placement of radiator and fans?
2. How to connect fans and pump to MB?

More details:

1. Basically, I have both fans and radiator inside chassis sucking the air from inside. I'm not sure though, whether the order should be: chassis, fans, radiator, rest of the PC (motherboard, power supply...) or it should be chassis, radiator, fans?

   Also I'm not sure what should be the best air flow direction in that case. It's not clear to me from the pictures in the manual.

   I found few videos of how to install Kraken x62 (I guess it's pretty much the same with x63), but they all say different things (fans out of the box, air flow should go out or in, somebody even has each fan on radiator in a different direction)

   Currently I have it like this - forepart of the chassis, radiator, both fans sucking air from inside the PC and blowing it out (I thought the radiator).

   Is this correct? Or would another configuration be more suitable? I also have another two fans at the end and at the top of the PC case, both sucking the air and pumping it outside.
2. Also, I wanted to ask how to connect the cooler to the MB. I connected the pump to CPU_FAN (although some instructions say it should be CPU_OPT) and both fans to SYS_FAN[5|6]_PUMP. Is this the preferred way?

This is my box: https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Cases/Mid-Tower-ATX-Cases/Carbide-Series-275Q-Mid-Tower-Quiet-Gaming-Case-%E2%80%94-Black/p/CC-9011164-WW

This is my MB: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X570-AORUS-MASTER-rev-1x#kfh

And here is the cooler: https://www.nzxt.com/products/kraken-x63

Any other advice regarding cooling would be welcome.

Here are the photos of how it's installed:

Inside the box:

[image: inside the box]

Front of the PC with cover:

[image: front of the PC with cover]

Front of the PC without cover:

[image: front of the PC without cover]